# remove space in QTableWidget cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to put a `QLineEdit` and `QLable` to the same cell in `QTableWidget`. This cell widget has created the code below I modified from the internet.

```
class HiddenLabel(QLabel):
    '''
    QLable hide when mouse pressed
    '''
    def __init__(self, buddy, taskline, parent = None):
        super(HiddenLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.buddy = buddy
        self.taskline = taskline

    # When it's clicked, hide itself and show its buddy
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # left click to edit 
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.hide()
            self.buddy.setText(self.taskline.plain_text)
            self.buddy.show()
            self.buddy.setFocus() # Set focus on buddy so user doesn't have to click again



class EditableCell(QWidget):
    '''
    QLineEdit show when HiddenLabel is hidden
    '''
    def __init__(self, taskline, parent = None):
        super(EditableCell, self).__init__(parent)
        self.taskline = taskline
        # Create ui
        self.myEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.myEdit.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.myEdit.hide() # Hide line edit
        self.myEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.textEdited)
        # Create our custom label, and assign myEdit as its buddy
        self.myLabel = HiddenLabel(self.myEdit, self.taskline) 
        self.myLabel.setText(self.taskline.enrich_text())
        # Change vertical size policy so they both match and you don't get popping when switching
        #self.myLabel.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed) 

        # Put them under a layout together
        hLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hLayout.addWidget(self.myLabel)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.myEdit)
        self.setLayout(hLayout)

    def textEdited(self):
        # If the input is left empty, revert back to the label showing
        print('edit finished')
        print(self.myEdit.text())
        taskline = TaskLine()
        taskline.parser(self.myEdit.text())
        self.taskline = taskline
        self.myLabel.setText(taskline.enrich_text())
        self.myEdit.hide()
        self.myLabel.show()
```

The cell will change between `QLineEdit` and `QLabel` by left click. 
[image]
As figured in the screenshot, I want to remove the blank space between the cell border and cell widget.

I think it can be adjusted by style setting, but I didn't find any useful documents about Qt style setting. I hope someone could give some use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the layout margins to 0:

```
hLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

since as [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) point out they are dependent on the style and platform:

> #### void QLayout::setContentsMargins(int left, int top, int right, int
>   bottom)
>
> Sets the left, top, right, and bottom margins to use around
>   the layout.
>
> By default, QLayout uses the values provided by the style. On most
>   platforms, the margin is 11 pixels in all directions.